# unable to set system property in gradle application

Tags: gradle

I am using `application` plugin in order to run my application. I want to set a property `prop` like this

```
-Dprop="some value"
```

To do that I added a line in my `build.gradle`

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dprop=$prop"]
```

My `build.gradle` looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName='my.package.Main'

run {
    // allows to run application { gradle run -Pdocument=["file.xml"] }
    if (project.hasProperty("document")) {
        args groovy.util.Eval.me(document)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ("org.apache.poi:poi:$apachePoiVersion")
    compile ("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:$apachePoiVersion")
}

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dprop=$prop"]
```

In my `Main` application I try to display it to check whether it's set or not

```
    try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml")) {
        LOGGER.info("System property prop: [{}].", System.getProperty("prop"));

    }
```

But it displays `System property prop: [null]`. 
I start the application like this

```
gradle run -Pprop="D://my-folder"
```

Property `-Pdocument="['']"` works fine. What is the problem?

Comment: I've just tried it out in an ad-hoc created application and it just works fine.

Comment: Please run gradle with `-d` switch and check in output if the property is passed and what value it has.

Comment: @Opal when I started to provide `system properties` using `systemProperty 'prop', project.getProperty('prop')` it started to work fine